# No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable when using Lazy<T>

Tags: c#, ninject, lazy-loading

Thanks in advance for those of you taking the time to read this!

I am attempting to use Ninject to resolve the items contained in a pair of cascading listboxes named CategoryListBox and SubCategoryListBox then Lazy Load a form when the SubCategoryListBox item is clicked.

I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface ICategory
{
    string Caption { get; set; }
    ISubCategory[] SubCategories { get; set; }
}

public interface ISubCategory
{
    string Caption { get; set; }
    Lazy<ISubForm> SubForm { get; set; }
}

public interface ISubForm
{
    void Show();
}
```

I have the following "Base" classes implement the interfaces:

```
public class BaseCategory : ICategory
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public ISubCategory[] SubCategories { get; set; }

    public BaseCategory(string caption, ISubCategory[] subCategories)
    {
        Caption = caption;
        SubCategories = subCategories;
    }
}

public class BaseSubCategory : ISubCategory
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public Lazy<ISubForm> SubForm { get; set; }

    public BaseSubCategory(string caption, Lazy<ISubForm> subForm)
    {
        Caption = caption;
        SubForm = subForm;
    }
}
```

I have 4 "Concrete" forms to implement the ISubForm interface as follows:

```
 public partial class SubForm1A : Form, ISubForm {}
 public partial class SubForm1B : Form, ISubForm {}
 public partial class SubForm2A : Form, ISubForm {}
 public partial class SubForm2B : Form, ISubForm {}
```

I have referenced Ninject and Ninject.Extensions.Factory via NuGet and my usings look like this

```
 using Ninject;
 using Ninject.Extensions.Factory;
```

My binding statements look like this:

```
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind<ICategory>().To<BaseCategory>().Named("Category 1").WithConstructorArgument("One");
        kernel.Bind<ISubCategory>().To<BaseSubCategory>().WhenParentNamed("Category 1").Named("SubCategory 1A").WithConstructorArgument("1A");
        kernel.Bind<ISubCategory>().To<BaseSubCategory>().WhenParentNamed("Category 1").Named("SubCategory 1B").WithConstructorArgument("1B");
        kernel.Bind<ISubForm>().To<SubForm1A>().WhenParentNamed("SubCategory 1A");
        kernel.Bind<ISubForm>().To<SubForm1B>().WhenParentNamed("SubCategory 1B");

        kernel.Bind<ICategory>().To<BaseCategory>().Named("Category 2").WithConstructorArgument("Two");
        kernel.Bind<ISubCategory>().To<BaseSubCategory>().WhenParentNamed("Category 2").Named("SubCategory 2A").WithConstructorArgument("2A");
        kernel.Bind<ISubCategory>().To<BaseSubCategory>().WhenParentNamed("Category 2").Named("SubCategory 2B").WithConstructorArgument("2B");
        kernel.Bind<ISubForm>().To<SubForm2A>().WhenParentNamed("SubCategory 2A");
        kernel.Bind<ISubForm>().To<SubForm2B>().WhenParentNamed("SubCategory 2B");
```

I populate the CategoryListBox datasource as follows:

```
        List<ICategory> categories = kernel.GetAll<ICategory>().ToList<ICategory>();

        CategoryListBox.DataSource = categories;
        CategoryListBox.DisplayMember = "Caption";
```

When you double-click the item in the CategoryListBox it populates the SubCategoryListBox as follows:

```
    private void CategoryListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ICategory selected = (ICategory)((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem;
        SubCategoryListBox.DataSource = selected.SubCategories;
        SubCategoryListBox.DisplayMember = "Caption";
    }
```

When you double-click the item in the SubCategoryListBox I attempt to lazy load the SubForm and that is when I run into the "No matching bindings are available" error

```
    private void SubCategoryListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ISubCategory selected = (ISubCategory)((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem;
        selected.SubForm.Value.Show();
    }
```

My goal is to not instantiate the SubForms until I click the SubCategoryListBox.

I am fairly certain I am going about it the wrong way and any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by adding **ninject.extensions.contextpreservation** to my references